# AWS CLI --query to select tag by value

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-rds

There were a lot of topics about this, but I still have a problem with a query.

I used:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds:eu-west-:xxxxx --query 'TagList[*]'
```

Output:

```json
{

    "Value": "test@test",
    "Key": "Owner"
},
{
    "Value": "XXXX",
    "Key": "Schedule"
}
```

I need to display only **XXXX** value. I tried:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds:eu-west-1:xxxxx --query 'TagList[].Tags[?Key==`Schedule`].Value[]' --output text
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give a try to this:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds:eu-west-:xxxxx --query "TagList[?Key=='Schedule'].Value[]"
```

Also, you may want to use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource --resource-name arn:aws:rds: | jq ".TagList[].Value"
```

Comment: Awesome, that's what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a nested `Tags` key inside the `TagList` list. Filter at the same level:

```
aws rds list-tags-for-resource \
--resource-name your:arn \
--query 'TagList[?Key==`Schedule`]'
```

Comment: it is almost what I expected, but nbari solution is better for me. However thank you for your help.